# How can I flip this pattern countdown pattern?

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm trying to create a countdown patten that asks the user for a number and prints a pyramid counting down to that number line by line. So if the user enters 5 the output is supposed to look like this :

```
        1
      2 1
    3 2 1
  4 3 2 1
5 4 3 2 1
```

So far I know that to count up my code should look like this:

```
Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

int n;
int j;
int temp = 0;
System.out.println("Please enter a number 1...9 :");

n = scnr.nextInt();

for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    for(j = 1; j <= i; ++j) {
        System.out.print(j + " ");
    }           
    System.out.println("");         
}
```

Which would print out this:

```
        1 
      1 2 
    1 2 3 
  1 2 3 4 
1 2 3 4 5
```

But how can I have it count to 5 on the left side?

Comment: The code you supplied doesn't print what you say it prints. Please update the code or the print.

Answer (score 3):

Below is solution with `Streams`, it could be to complicated for your approach with `for-loop`. But you can transform it aswell:

- first iterate over give `n` value
- then create string for each line for sub range (map `int` to `String`, and join them)
- after that you add extra spaces with `String.format`
- finally print it

```java
int n = 5;
String format = "%" + (n * 2) + "s";

IntStream.rangeClosed(1, n)
    .mapToObj(i -> IntStream.range(0, i)
        .mapToObj(j ->  i - j )
        .map(String::valueOf)
        .collect(Collectors.joining( " "))
    )
    .map(s -> String.format(format,s))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) 
{   
    // inner loop to handle number of leading spaces            
    for(int j = 2*(n-i); j >= 0; j--) 
    { 
        // printing spaces 
        System.out.print(" "); 
    } 

    //  inner loop to handle number of columns             
    for(int j = i; j > 0; j--) 
    { 
        // printing number 
        System.out.print(j + " "); 
    } 

    // ending line after each row 
    System.out.println(); 
}
```

This should help. To flip the patter basically you would have to play with leading spaces and numbers in reverse in inner loop.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**: if you take the difference from your target plus 1 for every number, you get your desired result: `5-5+1=1, 5-4+1=2, …, 5-1+1=5`.

So when printing the numbers, use `n-j+1` instead of plain `j`:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= n; ++i) {
    for (j = 1; j <= i; ++j) {
        System.out.print((n-j+1) + " "); // <-- here
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```